# show a textbox based on the selected option using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, drop-down-menu, textarea

I have a html form that includes droplist and textarea. What I need is to show the textarea  when the user selects an option from the droplist.

I already write the HTML code and the function for jQuery but the textarea doesn't show at all.

Where is the error in my code? 
I will appreciate any help.

## code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Form Validation</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified BootStarp CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function (){
        $("#droplistID").change(function(){
        $("#textarea").hide();
        $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
    });
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="page-wrapper" >
      <div class="container" >
        <h1>
          Send Post Data to AJAX
        </h1>
        <form name="myForm" class="form-horizontal" id ="myform" action="#" 
                onsubmit="return submitForm();" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-datam">
          <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">Form</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="name" class="col-md-4">Date *</label>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name"
                                placeholder="Enter Name" required/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" >
                      <label for="Title" class="col-md-4">Title *</label>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="mobile" name="phone"
                                 placeholder="Enter the Title" required/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group  ">
                      <label for="category" class="col-md-4">select Category *</label>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                       <select name = "droplist" id="droplistID" onChange="popupTextBox()">
                           <option id = "option1" value="select" selected>Select</option>
                           <option id = "option2" value="category 1">category 1</option>
                           <option id = "option3" value="category 2">category 2</option>
                           <option id = "option4" value="category 3">category 3</option>
                       </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id = "textarea">
                      <div class="form-group  ">
                         <label for ="text" class="col-md-4" >Enter a text </label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                           <textarea cols= "60" rows= "30"> </textarea>
                        </div>
                      </div>                      
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group  ">
                      <label for="image" class="col-md-4">Select Image </label>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" >
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">
            <center>
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
            </center>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you want `textarea` to appear when some value is selected from the droplist:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Form Validation</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified BootStarp CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $("#textarea").hide()
      $("#droplistID").change(function() {
        $(this).val() == 'select' ? $("#textarea").hide() : $("#textarea").show();
      });
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>
        Send Post Data to AJAX
      </h1>
      <form name="myForm" class="form-horizontal" id="myform" action="#" onsubmit="return submitForm();" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-datam">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
          <div class="panel-heading">Form</div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="name" class="col-md-4">Date *</label>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" required/>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="Title" class="col-md-4">Title *</label>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="phone" placeholder="Enter the Title" required/>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group  ">
                  <label for="category" class="col-md-4">select Category *</label>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <select name="droplist" id="droplistID">
                           <option id = "option1" value="select" selected>Select</option>
                           <option id = "option2" value="category 1">category 1</option>
                           <option id = "option3" value="category 2">category 2</option>
                           <option id = "option4" value="category 3">category 3</option>
                       </select>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div id="textarea">
                  <div class="form-group  ">
                    <label for="text" class="col-md-4">Enter a text </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <textarea cols="60" rows="30"> </textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group  ">
                  <label for="image" class="col-md-4">Select Image </label>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">
          <center>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
          </center>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i tried your answer it did not work 

i am using wordpress

Comment: This has nothing to do with WordPress. Question in code looks like a stand-alone page and a JQuery code.

Comment: yes its a stand alone page but i am using wordpress  as platform

Comment: Ok. ? So.. ? Did you check console for errors? _it did not work_ is vague and can't point to what did not work and where / what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
    $("#droplistID").change(function(){
        $(".hideOnLoad").show();       
    });
});
```

```css
.hideOnLoad {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Form Validation</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified BootStarp CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="page-wrapper" >
      <div class="container" >
        <h1>
          Send Post Data to AJAX
        </h1>
        <form name="myForm" class="form-horizontal" id ="myform" action="#" 
                onsubmit="return submitForm();" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-datam">
          <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">Form</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="name" class="col-md-4">Date *</label>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name"
                                placeholder="Enter Name" required/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" >
                      <label for="Title" class="col-md-4">Title *</label>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="mobile" name="phone"
                                 placeholder="Enter the Title" required/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group  ">
                      <label for="category" class="col-md-4">select Category *</label>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                       <select name = "droplist" id="droplistID">
                           <option id = "option1" value="select" selected>Select</option>
                           <option id = "option2" value="category 1">category 1</option>
                           <option id = "option3" value="category 2">category 2</option>
                           <option id = "option4" value="category 3">category 3</option>
                       </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id = "textarea">
                      <div class="form-group  ">
                         <label for ="text" class="col-md-4" >Enter a text </label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                           <textarea class='hideOnLoad' cols= "60" rows= "30"> </textarea>
                        </div>
                      </div>                      
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group  ">
                      <label for="image" class="col-md-4">Select Image </label>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" >
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">
            <center>
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
            </center>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You should hide the textarea using css. Then use the onchange handler to bind an action to the change event of the select box. If the select box changes, you show the textarea with class `.hideOnLoad.`

Comment: Post your code here (prefeably as a Stack Snippet), not just at a remote site.

Comment: It is not just a remote site. It's the actual code the OP asked, but adjusted to fix the issue? Could you please elaborate on why posting such a link is incorrect? Been doing this some time now...

Comment: [Is a link to jsfiddle with an explanation a valid answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308339/is-a-link-to-jsfiddle-with-an-explanation-a-valid-answer)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Guess I learned something today :). I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your jQuery function like this and get it working:

```
$(function() {
    $("#droplistID").change(function(event){
        if(event.target.value !== 'select'){
            $(".hideOnLoad").show();  //show if option 'select' is not selected
        } else{
            $(".hideOnLoad").hide();  //hide if option 'select' is selected
        }
    });
});
```